# Firebase Android+WebApp. How to Pass Auth from Android App to JavaScript in Webview

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Have an authenticated `Firebase` User in my `Android` App. `Webview` in the same `Android` App which loads a `HTML` page, need to access the `Firebase` DB via `Javascript`.

For the `Webview` to access the `Firebase` DB, need to authenticate again in the `javascript`. I can use `signInWithCustomToken()`, but `Android` App can't create custom token, have to call Server every time to create `CustomToken` and pass it to `webview`.

Is there any way I could pass Authentication From `Android` App to `Webview` inside that?